# Unable to use 'firebase-functions/v2/https' with expo SDK 49 and 2nd gen Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, expo

I upgraded my expo project to sdk49 with 2nd gen Firebase Functions but now i can't start my project with the expo Go app. i get this error message with 'npx expo start --clear' :

`Unable to resolve "firebase-functions/v2/https" from "functions/index.js"`

while it says on firebase docs to use firebase-functions/v2/https, i can't manage to make it work.
Anyone has the same problem ?

functions/index.js :

```
const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {setGlobalOptions, params} = require("firebase-functions/v2");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

setGlobalOptions({region: "europe-west1"});

exports.createPaymentIntent = onCall(
    async (data, context) => {
      const STRIPE_SECRET = params.defineString("STRIPE_SECRET");
      const stripe = require("stripe")(STRIPE_SECRET.value());
      const db = admin.firestore();

      // my function

    })
```

functions/package.json :

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1",
    "stripe": "^12.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

there is no v2 folder in the functions/node_modules/firebase-functions and i don't know how to get it.

i deployed my functions with `firebase deploy --only functions` and it went without error, all my functions are deployed.

I tried downgrading the node version to 16 then 18, with all the module updates.
I tried downgrading firebase-functions to multiple versions, nothing changed.
I tried calling https from firebase-functions/v2 in order to use https.onCall but nothing changed
`const {setGlobalOptions, params, https} = require("firebase-functions/v2");`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting a similar error when trying to run firebase emulators: `Cannot find module '/Users/.../functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https'`. I also don't have a v2 folder where it's looking for one.

Comment: Turns out I had two versions of the Firebase CLI installed on my Mac. When trying to run emulators it was using an old version, pre Gen 2. I deleted that one and now 'Firebase' commands are using the updated CLI.